# Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type

Tags: matlab, matrix-factorization

When I run the code below I got this error **Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type.**

```
function [R, Q] = rq_givens(A)
    Q = { eye(size(A,2)) };
    R = { A };              
    I =eye(size(A,1));
    Qs={ };
    k=1;
    for i=1:size(A,2)
       for j= size(A,1):-1:i+1
          y= -A(j,i); 
          x= A(i,i); 
          alpha = atan(y/x);
          c = cos(alpha);
          s= sin(alpha);
          temp = I;
          temp(i,i)=c;
          temp(i,j)=-s;
          temp(j,i)=s;
          temp(j,j)=c;
          A = temp * A;
          Qs{k} = temp;
          k=k+1;
       end
    end
    Q=I;
    for i=k-1:-1:1
       Q = Q*Qs{i}; 
    end    
    Q= Q';
    R= A;
end
```

It's an assignment that I am doing so all I can do is to change the function above,
The code to call the function is below and must stay the same.

```
A = randn(6,4);

[R,Q] = rq_givens(A)

for i = 1:length(R)
    disp("Q orthonormal?")
    Q{i}*Q{i}'
    Q{i}'*Q{i}
    disp("R upper triangular?")
    R{i}
end

R{end}*Q{end} - A % Equal ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Data types of R, Q are changed to numeric type from cell type inside function call.
At the second line, R is cell array, but the last line of function "rq_given" changes the type of R to numeric matrix.

Thus, R{i} is invalid. Similar issue can be seen with Q also.

Comment: How should I fix it? R and Q must be cell type ?

Comment: Yes, for the caller code to work, R and Q shall be cell type.